# How to get Emissive textures to render properly with transparency

Tags: rendering

I can't seem to get the same vibrancy with my exports when adding transparency to renders with emissive textures.

Even the difference of the image appearing in blender (view render) vs the PNG export is puzzling me.

Is there something obvious I'm missing to keep the same vibrancy?

[image]